# how to mock an angular service to return different results for different tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to test that the `loadResults()` method of my angular component always causes the `loading` member to become false, independent of whether an error was thrown or not:

component:

```
constructor(private service: Service1) {
}
    
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadResults();
}

private loadResults(): void {
    this.service.getResults().subscribe(results => {
        this.results = results;
        this.loading = false;
    },
    error => this.loading = false);
   }
}
```

service:

```
getResults(): Observable<Result[]> {
  return this.http.get<Result[]>(`${this.API_ROOT}/results`);
}
```

test:

```
class MockService {
  getResults(): Observable<Result[]> {
    return Observable.of([]);
  }
}

describe('Component: ResultList', () => {

  let resultList;
  let service;


  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new MockService();
    resultList = new ResultListComponent(service);
  });


  it('loading always set to false after the loadResults method', () => {
    resultList.ngOnInit();
    expect(resultList.loading).toBeFalsy();
  });

});
```

How can I modify this code to create a second test in which the same service method `(getResults)` throws an http error?

Answer (score 0):

got it:)

```
it('loading should be set to false after error', () => {
    jest.spyOn(service, 'getResults').mockImplementation(() => {
        return throwError(new Error('error'));
    });
    resultList.ngOnInit();
    expect(resultList.loading).toBeFalsy();
}
```